Why is it "keinen" instead of "keine" here in this dialogue?
This dialogue is excerpted from a Duolingo story:

Junior: Die klügsten Wissenschaftler glauben, dass es Außerirdische gibt!
Eddy: Ich kenne keine Wissenschaftler, die an Außerirdische glauben.
Junior: Wie viele Wissenschaftler kennst du persönlich?
Eddy: OK, keinen...

Why is it "keinen" instead of "keine" in Eddy's final response? It seems to call for plural accusative. I don't see why "keinen" could fit here.

Both the singular and the plural are often used with the number 0, and there are arguments for and against either.

The difference here is what is slightly referred to, or what you want to emphasize:

Ich kenne keine Wissenschaftler, die an Außerirdische glauben

You look at the overall ensemble of scientists, and you know none of them which believes in aliens. So the use of the plural ever so slightly shows you know or refer to many.

Ok, keinen...

"Not a single one". Here the use of the singular slightly emphasizes the small number. In my personal use I'd also pick the singular here, but I cannot give a good reason and it certainly is not mandatory.
Mind, that you could formulate either of these two sentences in plural or in singular, and the meaning would be virtually the same.
